# Is there any way to impliment Elliott–Rothenberg–Stock (ERS) with Hannan-Quinn lag selection criterion in R?

Tags: r, time-series, eviews

Hi TimeSeries and R gurus,

Is there any way to impliment Elliott–Rothenberg–Stock (ERS) with Hannan-Quinn lag selection criterion in R?

Libraries like urca, fUnitRoots and fSeries have commands for Elliott–Rothenberg–Stock unitroot test. However, I could not find any option where I can use HQIC for automatic lag length selection.

For example, here is what is available:

```
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, "gnp.r"])
ers.gnp <- ur.ers(gnp, type="DF-GLS", model="const", lag.max=4)
summary(ers.gnp)
```

I am after something like:

```
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, "gnp.r"])
ers.gnp <- ur.ers(gnp, type="DF-GLS", model="const", lag.max="HQIC")
summary(ers.gnp)
```

Aim is to get something like following produced in Eviews:

[image]

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Mubashir

Comment: URCA is using BIC here. As URCA is written in R, it would be very easy to modify the `ur.ers` code to use your own information criteria in place of BIC.

Comment: A. Webb, thanks for your time and suggestion. My questions is if there is any existing package to achieve this.

Comment: After spending a lot of time I found there is not any existing R packing to implement Elliott–Rothenberg–Stock (ERS) unitroot test with Hannan-Quinn (HQC) lag selection criterion...